# HH:MM:SS Countdowntimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I can't figure out how to make an HH:MM:SS Countdowntimer using Milliseconds.
I need to make a CountdownTimer telling how many hours, minutes, and seconds remain until the next day. Here is my code:

```
  final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   long timer = prefs.getLong("TIME", 86400000);
   new CountDownTimer(timer, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long elapsed) {

                                        time.setText(elapsed/3600000+":"+elapsed/1440000+":"+elapsed/?);
                              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                              editor.putLong("TIME",elapsed);
                              editor.commit(); 
         }
         public void onFinish() {

         }
      }.start();
```

P.S: Also, it will have to save the time left until last check. I look forward urgently to hearing from you guys. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculation is wrong, it should be:

```
final static long seconds_in_milllies = 1000L;
final static long minutes_in_millies = seconds_in_millies * 60;
final static long hours_in_millies = minutes_in_millies * 60;

// in onTick
long hours = elapsed / hours_in_millies;
elapsed %= hours_in_millies;
long minutes = elapsed / minutes_in_millies;
elapsed %= minutes_in_millies;
long seconds = elapsed / seconds_in_millies;
time.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds );
```

Comment: what if I want to display remaining days also??

Comment: Add another field final static long days_in_millies = hours_in_millies *24;
and inside on tick add this aswell  long days = elapsed / days_in_millies;
    elapsed%=days_in_millies;

Comment: Why does it have to be static?

Comment: It doesn't HAVE TO. However, since those are constant primitives, there's no need to create them for each object.